# Choppy Gradient on Splash Screen Windows Phone 7 Mango

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, expression-blend

Wondering if anyone knew a way to retain a good smooth gradient in a splash screen? I've tried both .jpg and loading the straight xaml as a logo control resource, and I've embedded in a viewbox. In the emulator it looks great! Though on the phone it still has that choppy 90's look to it and it's not doing my cool looking logo justice as a nifty splash screen. Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is known as banding and occurs on the phones by default because they are set to 16bbp. You can manually change it to 32bpp by adjusting yor `WMAppManifest.xml` file to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Deployment xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsphone/2009/deployment" AppPlatformVersion="7.1">
  <App xmlns="" BitsPerPixel="32" ...
```

([Source](http://www.istartedsomething.com/20111113/death-to-banding-windows-phone-devs-please-upgrade-your-apps-to-32-bitsperpixel/))

However, setting it like this to 32bpp can have a negative performance on your app. If you just need the gradient for your splash screen, you're better off [dithering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dither) the image beforehand. Whilst this won't give you a perfect gradient, it will reduce the banding effect. Essentially, setting the 32bpp setting above enables a dithering-like algorithm to affect the render (which is one of the reasons there can be a performance hit). If you use Photoshop, you can use this [dithering script](http://nerdplusart.com/photoshop-action-for-windows-phone-7-dithering) but pretty much any art application will have a way of adding noise to the image.